# Pointer scope and constructor creation for array of struct

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, struct, function-pointers

Jist of question detailed below:  Why do I get errors saying that `studentList` and `indexPtr` are not declared in this scope?

I wrote a program that was supposed to create an array of structures and allow the user to add, remove, and print items in that array.  The program worked fine, but I was unable to get the add, remove, and print functions to work properly on their own.  Everything worked perfectly if I had all of the code in my main function.

Now I am trying to rework my program and make it work by sending all of the info out to the proper functions, but I do not understand the proper way to send info back and forth from my main function.

Here is my header file for all my declarations:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define MAXSIZE 20;
using namespace std;

class Student
{
private:    
    struct studentEntry
    {
        string FIRST;
        string LAST;
        string ID;
        string CLASSIFICATION;
        string MAJOR;
    };
    int index;

public:
    void add(string &firstname, string &lastname, string &id, string &classification, string &major);
    void remove(string &id);
    void print(string &argument);
    int commandCompare(string &command);
    bool idCheck(string &id);
    Student();
};
```

And then here is some of my code from my file with all my functions in it, namely the very first thing which is a constructor for my student class.  What I was trying to do was create an array of student structures and a pointer to the index, so that I can use the same array in all the functions:

```
#include "students.h"

//constructor for Student class to create students array and pointer to index
Student::Student(){
    int *indexPtr = &index;
    studentEntry *studentList = new student[MAXSIZE];
}

//function to add entry to array of students
void Student::add(string &firstname, string &lastname, string &id, string &classification, string &major)
{
    string m_first = firstname; 
    string m_last = lastname;
    string m_id = id;
    string m_classification = classification;
    string m_major = major;
    int error = 0;

    //check if id is all digits, print error
    if (studentList[indexPtr]->idCheck(id) == false)
    {
        cout << "Error! ID can only contain digits." << endl;
        error = 1;
    }

    //search match for existing ids
    for(int i=0; i<indexPtr; i++)
    {
        //match found, print error, mark error true
        if(id.compare(studentList[i]->student->ID) == 0)
        {
            cout << "Error! ID already exists." << endl;
            error = 1;
        }   
    }

    else if(error != 1)
    {
        studentList[indexPtr]->FIRST = m_first;
        studentList[indexPtr]->LAST = m_last;
        studentList[indexPtr]->ID = m_id;
        studentList[indexPtr]->CLASSIFICATION = m_classification;
        studentList[indexPtr]->MAJOR = m_major;
        indexPtr = indexPtr++;
    }
}
```

I think everything in my program will work once I get the bits about the pointers and initial creation of my array ironed out.  Thanks a lot for any help!

edit:
Here is a snippet of my main function, just to show how I am calling the Student constructor and trying to call functions in the Student class:

```
int main()
{
    Student students;
    string command;
    int quit = 0;

    //loop while user command != quit
    do
    {       
        cout << "students> ";
        cin >> command;

        //if user command = add
        if(students.commandCompare(command) == 1)
        {   
            string first, last, id, classification, major;
            cin >> first >> last >> id >> classification >> major;
            students.add(first, last, id, classification, major);
        }
```

Comment: It is far from clear (to me, at least) what your actual question is...

Comment: @MatsPetersson I don't know why I get errors saying that `studentList` and `indexPtr` are not declared in this scope.  I assume it's because I am doing my constructor wrong, but I dont know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor:

```
Student::Student(){
    int *indexPtr = &index;
    studentEntry *studentList = new student[MAXSIZE];
}
```

These two lines are useless:

```
    int *indexPtr = &index;
    studentEntry *studentList = new studentEntry[MAXSIZE];
```

they create local variables and assign something to them, but then those local variables go out of scope.  You are also doing `new student` instead of `new studentEntry`.

I think you meant to put studentList and indexPtr in your class instead.

```
    int index;
    studentEntry *studentList;  // add this line
    int *indexPtr;              // add this line

public:
    void add(string &firstname, string &lastname, string &id, string &classification, string &major);
```

and change your constuctor like this:

```
Student::Student(){
    indexPtr = &index;
    studentList = new studentEntry[MAXSIZE];
}
```

Even better -- use the constructor initializer syntax:

```
Student::Student()
  : indexPtr(&index),
    studentList(new studentEntry[MAXSIZE])
{
}
```

And make sure you define a destructor to free the memory:

```
~Student()
{
    delete [] studentList;
}
```

And even better -- you can avoid manually allocating the memory at all if you use std::vector.

Another issue.  On this line:

```
#define MAXSIZE 20;
```

you have an extra semicolon.  It should just be

```
#define MAXSIZE 20
```

If you have the semicolon in there, then that semicolon gets placed in your code wherever MAXSIZE is used, so this line:

```
    studentList = new studentEntry[MAXSIZE];
```

would become

```
    studentList = new studentEntry[20;];
```

which is a syntax error.

Another issue -- lines like this:

```
    studentList[indexPtr]->FIRST = m_first;
```

should be like this:

```
    studentList[*indexPtr].FIRST = m_first;
```

`studentList` is a pointer, but `studentList[x]` is not.  Also, `indexPtr` is a pointer, so you have to indirect it first to get what it points to.

Comment: originally I had that line `studentEntry *studentList = new student[MAXSIZE];` in my class right after my struct, but that didnt work and I got the error that I couldnt have that in my class

Comment: I don't follow the constructor initializer syntax, but working with the suggestion before that, I changed my code to reflect your changes and I still get errors on that line, `expected type-specifier before student`.  Later in my functions when I want to use the array thats being created by the constructor, do I use `student` or `studentList`?

Comment: @manalishi: I missed that you also were doing `new student` instead of `new studentEntry`.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: okay, I thought that might be the case.  Unfortunately I still get an error that expected ']' before ';' token...why would this be?

Comment: @manalishi: You also have a problem with your MAXSIZE define.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: thanks, that helped solve that error.  now on to the real debugging!

Comment: do you see anything wrong with how I am using the studentEntry list in my add function?  I am getting errors regarding my use of `->`

Comment: thanks for the additional input.  What do you mean by "you have to indirect it first" regarding the `indexPtr` pointer?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25021/discussion-between-manalishi-and-vaughn-cato)